# SQL Select query when a condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
Site Owner |  Site URL    | Delete Site
 User #1   | google.com   |   Yes
 User #2   | google.com   |   Yes
 User #3   | yahoo.com    |   No
 User #4   | yahoo.com    |   Yes
 User #5   | hotmail.com  |   No
 User #6   | hotmail.com  |   NULL
```

I need to select all the Site URL where all the Site Owners have answered Yes. If one user from the same Site URL answer Yes and the other No, those I don't need. So for example I need in this example above to get google.com cause both users answer Yes.

Comment: What about Yes and null? Return or not?

Comment: No, those as well I don't need only the Site URL where all the Site Owners have answer Yes only. btw thanks for responding to my post so quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select site_url
from t
group by site_url
having min(delete_site) = 'yes' and max(delete_site) = 'yes' and
       count(*) = count(delete_site);  -- no NULL values;
```

You can actually simplify the `having` clause to:

```
having count(*) = sum(case when delete_site = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version of doing this. 
For null values I preferred to use ISNULL replacer, And IIF is used for decoding Yes No to countable number

```
SELECT 
  [Site Url]
FROM
 Table1
GROUP BY
 [Site Url]
HAVING 
  SUM( IIF(ISNULL([Delete Site], '')='Yes', 0, 1)) = 0
```

Comment: very helpful, really appreciated the assistance. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In simialry way you could also use of `not exists`

```
select * 
from table t 
where not exists (
    select 1 from table
    where [Site URL] = t.[Site URL]  and [Delete Site] <> 'Yes'
)
```